# Inconsistent data in cassandra. Read repair doesn't repair data

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I am using cassandra-2.0.9 and datastax-java-driver-3.0.0. some data for a particular partition key is not getting returned while reading with consistency level "LOCQL_QUORUM", but the same data can be read with consistency level "ALL". It sometimes throws DigestMismatchException in trace. Read repair is also not happening for that partition key. can anyone help to solve this?
FYI: I have checked "ntp", it's synchronized with ntp server.

Comment: What is the `read_repair_chance` value on that table?